# List of URL tags in HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

I need to replace all URLs within any website, also realtive URLs like /imgages/. Therefore I need a list of tags that can contain URLs which a browser would download such as href=, src=, url(). Are there any additions for HTML/CSS/JS?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by "tags" when talking about javascript?

You're not going to be able to do this generically for javascript. Any string may represent a URL; it can be dynamically generated / loaded from the server via AJAX / etc...

Comment: Well tags keywords anything that is likely to hold an URL. JS is obviously impossible to completely cover (I would need a JS engine and run the code) but maybe there are some common ajax method calls for http requests or similar. Any additional HTML and CSS infos would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to check inside scripts.